# How can I tell if the smallest angle between two 2d vectors if positive or negative without trigonometric functions?

Tags: vector, trigonometry

If you have to vectors [x, y] how can you tell if one is a clockwise or counter clockwise turn from the other one. Example a = [1,0] and b = [0,1] a to b is counter clockwise and b to a is clockwise. Can I do this without cos, sin, tan etc.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the cross product of the two vectors. In this case, since you have two-dimensional vectors, all you need is the coefficient of **k** (the unit vector in the Z direction: the cross product of two vectors in the XY plane is always in the Z direction), which is the determinant of the coefficients of the two vectors. If that comes out positive, then you rotate **a** counter-clockwise to get to **b**. If negative, you rotate clockwise. If zero, they point either in the same direction or in opposite directions, but rotation in either direction will require the same angle (0 or \pi) so you cannot determine the smaller one.

In the above case, det([1, 0], [0, 1]) = 1 and det([0,1], [1, 0]) = -1.